# How did word "problem" end up in the title?

Tags: discussion, support, title

While reviewing questions (request-close queue), I came across this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914852/can-someone-help-me-solve-this-problem-in-c-language

I didn't think the question should be closed, yet, before clicking "do not close" I went to edit this question to remove the deprecated tag *homework*.  I removed this tag, put a description of the edit and clicked "Save".  At this point I got the message about "Please do not use word 'problem' in the question title".  Fair enough, I removed that word.  However... How did this word end up in the title in the first place? The question is by a new user (rep of 1); if I can't post a question with word 'problem' in the title with my 12K+ rep, then a new user definitely shouldn't be able to.

Was this some sort of a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The title filter for "problem" is a relatively recent development. You just found a question that was posted before it was enabled.

To be specific, the question was posted in May 2011, and the filter was implemented around September 2011. I don't know the exact date, that's just an estimate based on when "why can't we use the word 'problem' in titles" posts started showing up on Meta.

EDIT:
The slightly less ridiculous metric of searching SO for [questions with "problem" in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3aproblem) supports the Sep. 2011 guess. There are a few dozen such questions on SO with later "asked on" dates, but they're all either

- migrations that started on sites without the title filter; or
- formatting hacks of varying cleverness ([zero-width spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm), anyone?)